# What is the best way to create custom item scrollable list view in c# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I want to create GUI application using .NET and I need to implement such kind of scrollable list with custom items. All items should grouped to 3 different groups and to include images, text and favourite star button as shown here:

[image: mockup]

I would also like to implement filtering using search box, but once I would be able to create such list with customizable items then I hope it would be much easier.

I tried using .NET list view, but I want each cell to look like 1 cell - with out any borders between the image, text, image.

I would extremely appreciate any thoughts about this manner!

Comment: This looks like an idea task for WPF.  If you need to do this in WinForms it's going to be a lot trickier.

Comment: Any idea for WinForms? what about WPF which component do you suggest using?

Comment: I don't know of anything pre-built in WinForms or WPF than can do exactly what you want.  You will definitely have to do some custom work.  In WPF this would be a stackPanel with other elements inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be making control template for either WPF `ListView` or `ListBox` control.

For example, `ListBox.ItemTemplate` allows for custom item look.

If you would like to use 3rd party components, [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) allows this using owner drawing (requires subclassing `BetterListView`):

[image]

Here is a setup code for the control:

```
this.customListView = new CustomListView
                        {
                            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                            Parent = this
                        };

this.customListView.BeginUpdate();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    var item = new BetterListViewItem
                {
                    Image = imageGraph,
                    Text = String.Format("Item no. {0}", i)
                };

    this.customListView.Items.Add(item);
}

var group1 = new BetterListViewGroup("First group");
var group2 = new BetterListViewGroup("Second group");
var group3 = new BetterListViewGroup("Third group");

this.customListView.Groups.AddRange(new[] { group1, group2, group3 });

this.customListView.Items[0].Group = group1;
this.customListView.Items[1].Group = group1;

this.customListView.Items[2].Group = group2;
this.customListView.Items[3].Group = group2;
this.customListView.Items[4].Group = group2;

this.customListView.Items[5].Group = group3;

this.customListView.AutoSizeItemsInDetailsView = true;
this.customListView.GroupHeaderBehavior = BetterListViewGroupHeaderBehavior.None;
this.customListView.ShowGroups = true;

this.customListView.LayoutItemsCurrent.ElementOuterPadding = new Size(0, 8);

this.customListView.EndUpdate();
```

and `CustomListView` class (implements custom drawing and interaction with star icons):

```
using BetterListView;

internal sealed class CustomListView : BetterListView
{
    private const int IndexUndefined = -1;

    private Image imageStarNormal;
    private Image imageStarHighlight;

    private int lastStarIndex = IndexUndefined;
    private int currentStarIndex = IndexUndefined;

    public CustomListView()
    {
        this.imageStarNormal = Image.FromFile("icon-star-normal.png");
        this.imageStarHighlight = Image.FromFile("icon-star-highlight.png");
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);

        var item = HitTest(e.Location).ItemDisplay;

        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var bounds = GetItemBounds(item);

        if (bounds == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Rectangle boundsStar = GetStarBounds(bounds);

        UpdateStarIndex(boundsStar.Contains(e.Location)
            ? item.Index
            : IndexUndefined);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        UpdateStarIndex(IndexUndefined);
    }

    protected override void OnDrawGroup(BetterListViewDrawGroupEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        eventArgs.DrawSeparator = false;

        base.OnDrawGroup(eventArgs);
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(BetterListViewDrawItemEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(eventArgs);

        Graphics g = eventArgs.Graphics;
        BetterListViewItemBounds bounds = eventArgs.ItemBounds;

        int imageWidth = this.imageStarNormal.Width;
        int imageHeight = this.imageStarNormal.Height;

        g.DrawImage(
            (this.currentStarIndex == eventArgs.Item.Index) ? this.imageStarHighlight : this.imageStarNormal,
            GetStarBounds(bounds),
            0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        Rectangle boundsSelection = bounds.BoundsSelection;

        g.DrawRectangle(
            Pens.Gray,
            new Rectangle(boundsSelection.Left, boundsSelection.Top, boundsSelection.Width - 1, boundsSelection.Height - 1));
    }

    private void UpdateStarIndex(int starIndex)
    {
        if (starIndex == this.lastStarIndex)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool isUpdated = false;

        if (this.lastStarIndex != IndexUndefined)
        {
            Items[this.lastStarIndex].Invalidate();

            isUpdated = true;
        }

        if (starIndex != IndexUndefined)
        {
            Items[starIndex].Invalidate();

            isUpdated = true;
        }

        this.lastStarIndex = this.currentStarIndex;
        this.currentStarIndex = starIndex;

        if (isUpdated)
        {
            RedrawItems();
        }
    }

    private Rectangle GetStarBounds(BetterListViewItemBounds bounds)
    {
        Rectangle rectInner = bounds.BoundsInner;

        int widthImage = this.imageStarNormal.Width;
        int heightImage = this.imageStarNormal.Height;

        return (new Rectangle(
            rectInner.Width - widthImage,
            rectInner.Top + ((rectInner.Height - heightImage) >> 1),
            widthImage,
            heightImage));
    }
}
```